# Is there C# alternative to java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode in java?

Tags: java, c#, base64

I am rewriting this piece of code and couldn't find C# alternative.

```
java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(bytes)
```

Also, I don't see any mentioning of MIME scheme in official **.NET Core** **base64** converter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-6.0

Could you help me find an alternative?

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes))`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine no it's completely different result. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html
Please see MIME decoding. The result is different from the C# decoding

Comment: @Charlieface no, it's decoding simple base64 basic, please see: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html 
I need to have mime decoding